# Twilio verification doesn't work it keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, twilio

I'm using React Native
I'm staying on the same issue over and over again.

This code uses axios. I don't know why it keeps returning undefined. I wrote all of my twilio ids correctly.

I used serverless twilio it worked but I didn't know how I could change it my way.
If I can't use this code anymore, please let me know if there is another good way.
I don't know how to use node.js.
I'd appreciate your help.

Here is the code.

**Fetch.js**

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
  value: true,
});
exports.default = void 0;

var _querystring = _interopRequireDefault(require('querystring'));

var _axios = _interopRequireDefault(require('axios'));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
  return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {default: obj};
}

class Fetch {
  constructor({twilioServiceSid, twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken}) {
    const fetch = _axios.default.create({
      baseURL: `https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/${twilioServiceSid}`,
      auth: {
        username: twilioAccountSid,
        password: twilioAuthToken,
      },
    });

    this.fetch = fetch;
  }

  async post({path, payload}) {
    try {
      const obj = {
        To: payload.phone,
        Channel: 'sms',
      };

      if ('code' in payload) {
        obj['Code'] = payload.code;
      }

      const {status, data} = await this.fetch.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: path,
        data: _querystring.default.stringify(obj),
      });
      return {
        status,
        data,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
}

exports.default = Fetch;
```

**Verify.js**

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
  value: true,
});
exports.default = void 0;

var _phone = _interopRequireDefault(require('phone'));

var _fetch = _interopRequireDefault(require('./fetch'));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
  return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {default: obj};
}

class Serify {
  constructor({twilioServiceSid, twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken}) {
    this.fetch = new _fetch.default({
      twilioServiceSid,
      twilioAccountSid,
      twilioAuthToken,
    });
    this.twilioAccountSid = twilioAccountSid;
    this.twilioAuthToken = twilioAuthToken;
  }

  async start({phone, country}) {
    try {
      const number = (0, _phone.default)(phone, country ? country : 'USA');

      if (!number) {
        throw new Error(
          'Invalid phone number. Please provide the country code in an ISO-3166 alpha 3 format.',
        );
      }

      const response = await this.fetch.post({
        path: 'Verifications',
        payload: {
          phone: number,
        },
      });
      return {
        code: response.status,
        data: response.data,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return new Error(error);
    }
  }

  async verify({phone, country, code}) {
    try {
      const number = (0, _phone.default)(phone, country ? country : 'USA');

      if (!number) {
        throw new Error(
          'Invalid phone number. Please provide the country code in an ISO-3166 alpha 3 format.',
        );
      }

      if (code.length <= 3) {
        throw new Error('Invalid SMS code.');
      }

      const response = await this.fetch.post({
        path: 'VerificationCheck',
        payload: {
          phone: number,
          code: code.toString(),
        },
      });
      return {
        code: response.status,
        data: response.data,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return new Error(error);
    }
  }
}

exports.default = Serify;
```

```
  const verify = new Serify({
    twilioServiceSid: '', 
    twilioAccountSid: '', 
    twilioAuthToken: '', 
  });
    try {
      const ss = await verify.start({
        phone: '+1456123123',
      });
      console.log(ss);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure which part you are saying is returning undefined. But, there is a bigger issue here.

When building a native application, you cannot embed your Twilio credentials within the app and make API requests direct to Twilio from the application. A malicious user could decompile the application, extract your account credentials and abuse your Twilio account.

You should not make the API request from your application. Instead, you should build a server side proxy that stores your Twilio credentials and makes the API request, which you trigger from the application.

I don't have an example of this for Twilio Verify and React Native, but the theory is the same as [sending an SMS from a React application](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-an-sms-react-twilio).

If you had managed to implement this using Twilio Serverless, then you should go back to that version. If you have trouble with that, I would ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but I don't want to use Node.js backend server. can I use Twilio without using Node.js backend?

Comment: You can use it with whatever back-end server you like, it doesn't have to be Node.js. It does have to be a back-end server (or serverless function) though. Otherwise you cannot protect your credentials and are at risk of attack.

Comment: I already have serverless function In my project I don't know how to call it whatever I want. could you explain that? or link please. I'm not good at English I was rude I'm sorry.

Comment: The serverless function has a URL, you should call it the same way you are trying to call the Twilio API, for example, using axios.

Comment: I did this https://www.twilio.com/blog/serverless-phone-verification    
fetch('https://myprojectname.twil.io/start-verify', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {to: '+15235235233', channel: 'sms', locale: 'en'},
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    }).then(res => console.log(res));

I wrote like that I just got an error that "Missing parameter; please provide a phone number or email.", did I wrong?

Comment: Try JSON stringifying your body. `body: JSON.stringify({to: '+15235235233', channel: 'sms', locale: 'en'})`.

Comment: More than happy to help!